# Is it possible to cache null with hibernate and ehcache?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

Does anyone know if it possible to cache nulls with hibernate 2nd level cache and ehcache ?

I mean when an entryKey is not found in DB i would like that  entryKey in the cache with a null meaning that is not present in DB. I would like to avoid query's to DB when it's known an element is not in DB.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't directly store null in ehcache, as ehcache does not support null as cache key or cache value.

But off course, for the data not found in DB case, you can always save some other convenient object (e.g. an empty object {}, a boolean false, or any object of your choice to identify not found case) in cache, and later the same object will be returned from cache.

Comment: Yes, i know that. But it's possible do it with hibernate-ehcache ? It's a library

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think it is possible. This is coming from Hibernate.

If you add a query cache, it will probably work.

Also, if you add Spring cache, it will work as well.

Ehcache indeed doesn't support null (for complicated technical reasons), however it is fairly easy to set a `NullObject` instance instead. This is what Spring does.

Hibernate-ehcache is an Hibernate cache implementation for Ehcache 2. So it won't help you.

My recommendation will be to use a layer of caching above hibernate. Like Spring Cache or directly Ehcache. It will do exactly what you want and even be faster.